Azure SWA CLI localhost:4280 is not working
I want to build a local development environment for Azure Static Web Apps using SWA CLI. The Client is a Blazor WASM.
I installed SWA CLI successfully using the command:
npm install -g @azure/static-web-apps-cli

The Blazor client is working fine when started from Visual studio using F5

Running swa init command produced this file swa-cli.config.json
{
  "$schema": "https://aka.ms/azure/static-web-apps-cli/schema",
  "configurations": {
    "blazor-app3": {
      "appLocation": ".",
      "outputLocation": "bin\\wwwroot",
      "appBuildCommand": "dotnet publish -c Release -o bin",
      "run": "dotnet watch run",
      "appDevserverUrl": "http://localhost:5050"
    }
  }
}```



When I run 'swa start' command I get this

`
C:\Users\emad\source\repos\BlazorApp3\BlazorApp3>swa start

Welcome to Azure Static Web Apps CLI (1.1.8)

Using configuration "blazor-app3" from file:
  C:\Users\emad\source\repos\BlazorApp3\BlazorApp3\swa-cli.config.json

***********************************************************************
* WARNING: This emulator may not match the cloud environment exactly. *
* Always deploy and test your app in Azure.                           *
***********************************************************************

[run] dotnet watch  Hot reload enabled. For a list of supported edits, see https://aka.ms/dotnet/hot-reload.
[run]    Press "Ctrl + R" to restart.
[run] dotnet watch  Building...
[swa]
[swa] Found configuration file:
[swa]   C:\Users\emad\source\repos\BlazorApp3\BlazorApp3\staticwebapp.config.json
[swa]
[swa] - Waiting for http://localhost:5050 to be ready
[run]   Determining projects to restore...
[run]   All projects are up-to-date for restore.
[run]   BlazorApp3 -> C:\Users\emad\source\repos\BlazorApp3\BlazorApp3\bin\Debug\net8.0\BlazorApp3.dll
[run]   BlazorApp3 (Blazor output) -> C:\Users\emad\source\repos\BlazorApp3\BlazorApp3\bin\Debug\net8.0\wwwroot
[run] dotnet watch  Started
[swa] √ http://localhost:5050 validated successfully
[run] info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
[run]       Now listening on: http://localhost:5050
[swa]
[swa] Using dev server for static content:
[swa]   http://localhost:5050
[swa]
[swa] Azure Static Web Apps emulator started at http://localhost:4280. Press CTRL+C to exit.
[swa]
[swa]
[run] info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
[run]       Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
[run] info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
[run]       Hosting environment: Development
[run] info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
[run]       Content root path: C:\Users\emad\source\repos\BlazorApp3\BlazorApp3
[run] dotnet watch ⌚ Connecting to the browser is taking longer than expected ...
`


The browser is opening localhost:5050 

The problem is : If I try to open the localhost:4280 to see the "emulated" site. I always get an error ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED


[![enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/efEcfYvI.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/efEcfYvI.png)


I had nodejs v20 when I was having this issue.
Downgrading to nodejs v16 fixed the issue.

I had a same problem, and it is also working on v18.

To avoid downgrading the global node version because of Static Web Apps (SWA), you may install the SWA and the downgraded node in the project level:
npm install -D @azure/static-web-apps-cli

And then the node version:
npm install -D node@18


Note: Verify the version with the npx node -v command

Finally, you can start the emulation with npx to run the command with the local packages:
npx swa start ./build --data-api-location swa-db-connections

